# Guidance does not exist here

Tags: support, duplicates

So I have a problem with my VirtualBox Windows 7 64 guest.
It seems that it does not recognize the GPU.

While researching the problem I cam across this post .... [Enable CUDA GPU working under VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598317/enable-cuda-gpu-working-under-vm) ... underneath the post is a message about this post being a duplicate and that the answer is elsewhere.

So here is my question...
If you are going to claim that a question is answered some place on the system why not put a link to that answer?

How are we supposed to get assistance if you block one question from being answered yet do not provide with a location where the problem is resolved?

I still have my problem but have no clear path to find the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Look right under the question's title where it links to its duplicate question:

> <sub>**This question already has an answer here:**</sub>
>   [Enable graphics card in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/139320/)  *3 answers*

Answer (score 8):

As karel indicated, **this already is done for you** - right under the question's title is a box where it shows the link to the duplicate.

In the mobile app, this is along a bar/box at the *bottom* of the post window/screen.  It says that the post is marked as a duplicate, and there's a nice little info button there that'll show you details of the duplicate and the link to the dupe.